# Graphql - get full sub-object, or null if doesn't exist

Tags: mongoose, graphql

I have a graphql query which gets a `Meeting` object with `Client` object:

```
type Meeting {
  address: String!
  client: Client
}
type Client {
  displayName: String!
}
```

The `displayName` is required, but `client` isn't.
If I'm querying it as

```
{
  getMeeting(meetingId: "43bbea6ea0c6112b0abcf11d") {
    address
    client {
      displayName
    }
  }
}
```

And this meeting doesn't have a client, then I'm getting an error:

```
Error: Cannot return null for non-nullable field Client.displayName.
```

I just want that if there is a client, I will get its full details. And if there isn't, I will get `client: null`.

If I will remove the required from the `displayName`, it will work also when client is null and I will get

`"client": {
   "displayName": null
 }`

as I've expected. But I'm still looking for a way to enforce the required on the `displayName` - only if there is a client.

Is there any way to do that in graphql?

Comment: How does your query resolver look like?

Comment: I've checked again the resolvers after your comment, and it wasn't the problem but it helped me to get to the real problem which is because of mogoose, I've posted an answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was because of `mongoose`.

When I'm fetching the data from the DB, mongoose adds the empty embedded subdocument of `client: {}` even if there is no such key in the `meeting` document in the DB (and `console.log(meeting)` doesn't show this field - Only `console.log(meeting.client)` prints `client: {}`).

Hence `graphql` tries to return the required field of `client`, because `client` is not `undefined` as I thought.