# How to return an object or null in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

I have the following schema:

```
type User {
    email: String!,
    user_id: String!,
    img: String!,
},

type Query {
    getUser(user_id: String!): User
}
```

The schema reflects the fact that I must return an `User` object. However, I can not always do this, and sometimes I need to return null. For example, if I make a request to the DB, it will return return object or null (if the user was not found).

In my GraphQL schema, I set the type for a particular field. If I try to return a different type than what I set, I get an error. How do I allow a field to return either an object or null?

Comment: I see only one way nothing to return if DB give null.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Type-System.Non-Null):

> By default, all types in GraphQL are nullable; the null value is a valid response for all of the above types. To declare a type that disallows null, the GraphQL Non‐Null type can be used.

In other words, types in GraphQL are nullable **by default**. So a field like

```
getUser: User
```

may return either a `User` object or null. A field like

```
name: String
```

may return either a String or null. Only by explicitly specifying a field as non-null (in SDL, by appending a `!` to the type), can we specify that a field should never return null. For example:

```
name: String!
```

It's also important to note that the Promise returned in your resolver must resolve to either `null` or `undefined` in order to be coerced into a null value. In other words, if you return an empty object (`{}`), an empty array (`[]`) or some other value, GraphQL will treat this as you returning an object and not a null value!

In your schema, the `email` field on User is `String!`, meaning it cannot resolve to null. If you run a query like

```
query {
  getUser(user_id: "1") {
    email
  }
}
```

and the resolver for `getUser` returns an empty object (`{}`), GraphQL will attempt to resolve `email`, return null for it and blow up because `email` is not supposed to be null! If, however, `getUser` resolves to null, none of the child fields will be resolved and you will not get any error.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Graphql - get full sub-object, or null if doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43045639/graphql-get-full-sub-object-or-null-if-doesnt-exist), you get the error you describe when you return empty object (i.e. {}) instead of null from your GraphQL function.

I had similar problem: I kept getting the "error: lack the require field" error in GraphQL response until I made sure I was actually returning null, not empty object.